# GWT 2.6: Compiler Report does not show Compiler Metrics?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt

I am using GWT 2.6 and wanted to create a compiler report as described here: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompileReport.html

Using the

```
-XsoycDetailed
```

option generated a compiler report like this:

[image]

It turns out that there is no source available for the listed "Compiler Metrics" links.

**What are they good for? Is there another option to output these pages too?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `-XcompilerMetrics` as parameter to GWT compiler.

Compiler metrics shows source files found by the compiler and also which classes were compiled into js and which were ignored, because they are not reachable from entry point.

Comment: Also, have a look at the release notes of the 2.5.0 RC1 version for some explanation: http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html?csw=1#Release_Notes_2_5_0_RC1 (Look towards the end of section Breaking Changes and Other Changes of Note.)